# Monodevelop, VS Code and VS2017 new csproj file format

Tags: visual-studio-code, monodevelop, visual-studio-2017

Is Monodevelop or VS Code supporting VS2017 new csproj file format?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio for Mac will support it. Currently that is using MonoDevelop 7.0. Neither of these have been officially released.

VS Code supports the new csproj project file format if you update the C# extension.

Comment: Does it mean Monodevelop will not be officially supported on Windows Linux?

Comment: Do VS for Mac and MonoDevelop support the new format on Mono, or just .NET Core?

Comment: You can have an SDK style project that targets the .NET Framework. On Linux and the Mac that project would run with Mono with MonoDevelop and VS Mac.